# How to add column and assigning values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns `name` and `category` :

| Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| A | High |
| b | Medium |
| c | Low |

I would like to add another column in it and assign values to category with SQL

Desired result:

| Name | Category | V_Cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | High | 1 |
| B | Medium | 2 |
| C | Low | 3 |

I am mostly used to python and not SQL any clue ? I am using SQL Server.

Thank you

Comment: `ALTER TABLE [TableX] ADD COLUMN [V_Cat] int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`.

Comment: Tank you and how to asseign High = 1 Medium = 2 and Low = 3 ?  in V_cat

Comment: @sarah looks like you need a separate table category that holds categories names and their values and in your first table add a foreign key to your category FK_category

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is a *computed column*:

```
ALTER TABLE TableX ADD V_Cat AS
    (CASE Category WHEN 'High' THEN 1 WHEN 'Medium' THEN 2 WHEN 'Low' THEN 1 END);
```

Note that you can simply use the `CASE` expression in a `SELECT` query as well.

However, if you want these to be used across different tables and flexible (so you can add additional categories), then I would recommend a *reference* table.  That is, only store the `v_cat` column in your table and have another table with the strings that these mean.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to `ALTER` your `TableX`:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableX] ADD [V_Cat] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

And for assign values, if you have same order by name values, you can use this sample:

```
SELECT [Name], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Name]) AS RowNo 
INTO #t_res
FROM TableX;

UPDATE X 
SET X.V_Cat = t.RowNo
FROM TableX AS X
JOIN #t_res AS t ON t.[Name] = X.[Name];
```

It will work for more unlimited records that have same order by name.